# hbase 1.1.2 cannot start up ？something wrong with classpath ？

Tags: linux, apache, hbase, startup

```
[root@localhost local]# ll
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   11 Sep 12 21:34 hbase -> hbase-1.1.2
drwxr-xr-x. 30 root root 4096 Sep 12 21:34 hbase-1.1.2

[root@localhost local]# ./hbase/bin/start-hbase.sh
Error: Could not find or load main class。            org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKServerTool
starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase/logs/hbase-root-master-localhost.out
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster
starting regionserver, logging to /usr/local/hbase/logs/hbase-root-1-regionserver-localhost.out
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer
```

Why does it show this error? The class file exists.

```
[root@localhost local]# find ./ -name HBaseConfTool.class
./hbase-1.1.2/hbase-server/target/classes/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/HBaseConfTool.class
```

The `/etc/profile`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_20
export HBASE_HOME=/usr/local/hbase
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HBASE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$HBASE_HOME/hbase-server/target/classes
```

I add `$HBASE_HOME/hbase-server/target/classes`, but it still does not find the class file。
I am just a newer，getting start follow official docs, but can not run。I am so eggache... sos...

---

thanks for you asking my quesiton。

I get the src version, and I use "mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip.exec=true  -Dtar -e" compile，I hope it makes hbasexx-bin.tar.gz，but  get nothing。

Complie hadoop src use 'mvn package -Pdist,native,docs -DskipTests -Dtar' ，then the xx.tar.gz can be found in hadoop-dist/target/ 。
Maybe my hbase compile command is wrong? I copy it from others。what is the right complie commad ？ I am not familiar with mvn params 。。。

---

```
/usr/local/hbase-1.1.2/bin/hbase --config conf classpath
```

I find that many main module path is the old compile path,

```
/root/hbase-1.1.2/hbase-it/target/hbase-it-1.1.2-tests.jar:/root/hbase-1.1.2/hbase-common/target/hbase-common-1.1.2.jar:/root/hbase-1.1.2/hbase-protocol/target/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.jar:/root/hbase-1.1.2/hbase-client/target/hbase-client-1.1.2.jar:
```

Oh my god,but how to complie in path /root compile /root/hbase-1.1.2 ,then I mv to /usr/local ? or how to modify classpath when I use in path /usr/local/hbase-1.1.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using source package. 
Try binary package (http://apache.mirror.cdnetworks.com/hbase/1.1.2/hbase-1.1.2-bin.tar.gz) or build it first.

not "hbase-1.1.2-src.tar.gz"

but "hbase-1.1.2-bin.tar.gz"